# PHP variable breaking AJAX code

Tags: php, ajax

I am adding a textarea inside a form that is within a table in order for users to write comments for their order. 
My application is a shopping cart app, and everything works well, until I add a particular PHP variable. I will start with the code.

AJAX code to add item to cart on index.php:

```
if(product_quantity > 0)  
       { 
            $.ajax({  
                 url:"action.php",  
                 method:"POST",  
                 dataType:"json",  
                 data:{  
                      product_id:product_id,   
                      product_name:product_name,   
                      product_price:product_price,   
                      product_quantity:product_quantity,   
                      action:action  
                 },  
                 success:function(data)  
                 {  
                      $('#order_table').html(data.order_table);  
                      $('.badge').text(data.cart_item);  
                      alert("Product has been Added into Cart");  
                 }  
            });  
       }
```

action.php:

```
$order_table .= ' 
            <tr>
            <td colspan="3" align="right"><span style="font-size:1.3em;">Tax</span></td>
            <td align="right">$'.number_format($tax,2).' </td> 
            </tr>
            <tr> 
                 <td colspan="3" align="right"><span style="font-size:1.3em;">Total</span></td>  
                 <td align="right">$ '.number_format($total, 2).'</td>  
                 <td></td>  
            </tr>  
            <tr>  
                 <td colspan="5" align="center">  
                 <form method="post" action="cart.php">
                        <textarea name="comments" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter any special instructions for the order">
                        '.$_SESSION["comment"].'
                        </textarea> <br>
                           <input type="submit" name="place_order" class="btn btn-warning" value="Place Order" />  
                        </form>
                 </td>  
            </tr>  
       ';  
  }  
  $order_table .= '</table>';  
  $output = array(  
       'order_table'     =>     $order_table,  
       'cart_item'          =>     count($_SESSION["shopping_cart"])  
  );  
  echo json_encode($output);
```

The problem is that when adding the piece of code in action.php `$_SESSION["comment"]` in the text area in order to preserve what customer already wrote, the application stops prompting the alert on the index page `alert("Product has been Added into Cart");` and also stops showing that there are items added to cart when navigating to the cart tab, therefore the table does not show at all even though the items do get added to the actual session variable AKA the cart. Any ideas? Thanks you.

Comment: You may need to strip any html characters present in `$_SESSION["comment"]`, to make sure it doesn't try to break out of the textarea. If it should just be comments and nothing code, then you definitely want to make sure it's cleaned to prevent XSS. Otherwise, look at the source code in your browser once the page is rendered to see what's breaking it.

Comment: I see an `}` before `$order_table .= '</table>';` but I dont see any `{` in your action.php

Comment: @aynber Yes definitely will strip it as soon as I get things working. And nothing seems to be broken, the html looks good. Thanks

Comment: @blueqn because the page has a ton of code, and I only posted the relevant part. Thanks

Comment: Add all the code on action.php